# UIImagePicker custom "Move and Scale"

Tags: iphone, image, uiimagepickercontroller, scale

I'm trying to make Move and Scale, with UIImagePicker.

I want to change "Move and Scale" string and change the cancel and Choose button title into another string. Is there any way to do that ?

For more details Look at these

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to change the text to?
Also how are you adding the UITextView and the UIButton in the design?